# how to break up the monolithic mkYesod block safely

Tags: haskell, module, hierarchy, yesod

This question is more to help my understanding of Yesod than anything else.  Take the example at http://www.yesodweb.com/book/basics and in particular the code generated by the *mkYesod* **TH** function.

The problem that I perceive is that this **TH** generates both the route data type (*data Route HelloWorld = HomeR*) and the *yesodDispatch* function which calls *getHomeR* etc.

The difficulty there is that in a larger project you can't split out the definition of *getHomeR* into a separate module because Haskell's simple module system is strictly hierarchical;  so if *getHomeR* simply called *getHomeRimplementation* which were defined in another module (say **HomeImplementation**) then that module would need to import the definition of *data Route HelloWorld* and there would be a circular dependency.

It seems to me that this could be avoided if the *RenderRoute*, *ParseRoute* and *YesodDispatch* instances could be declared in separate modules;  then *RenderRoute* could be at the bottom of the importation hierarchy, and *YesodDispatch*, at the top.  Does that make sense ?  Maybe the fact that I ask this question shows that I don't understand something about the *mkYesod* **TH**;  e.g., that there is some crucial interrelationship and they should not be separated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct, but that point is also addressed in the yesod book. For example have a look at http://www.yesodweb.com/book/scaffolding-and-the-site-template, the section called "Foundation and Application modules". Usually you have a Foundation module that defines route types and handler functions, and an Application module that defines the dispatching. So all your handler modules import Foundation, and Application imports all your handle modules and Foundation. No cycles!

You may be also interested in reading http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2012/10/yesod-pure, about using Yesod without  TH.

Look at samples yesod applications in Github. For example, I've developed a simple Yesod app to demonstrate electronic payments at https://github.com/JPMoresmau/mangopay/tree/master/yesod-mangopay/app. You'll see that multi module approach there.

Comment: This is becoming infuriating.  I have Foundation.hs thus:

_-- | The foundation object
data JRState = JRState {
  ...
 }

YC.mkYesodData "JRState" RouteData.routeData

instance YA.YesodAuth JRState where
   ..._

along with all the other instance declarations, then in Main.hs:

_import Foundation

Y.mkYesodDispatch "JRState" resourcesJRState_

but the compiler warns "Orphan instance: instance Y.YesodDispatch JRState" and dispatching (e.g., new account creation via the route " /auth AuthR YA.Auth Yesod.Auth.getAuth") doesn't work.  Help !

Comment: I note that you simply suppress the warning in mangopay's Application.hs so maybe my suspicion about the warning is misplaced.  The full horror is at https://github.com/mounty1/JackRose.git

Comment: An orphan instance is not a problem here : orphan instances are instances that are created in another module than the data type declaration and the risk is that someone else declare another instance in another module so you get a conflict with two such orphans... But here your instance is for your own data type, specific to your application thus it won't be declared in another of your import !

Comment: Sorry for the noise everyone.  The problem was entirely specific to my application and not related to routing.  Just in case anyone else encounters it, I'd enabled SSL-only connections in my *instance Yesod App* declaration, but was connecting via port 3000 which I think my local firewalld or iptables was blocking.